# How to change the default browser?

Tags: android

I want my button to bring up the default browser selector to handle action with. I have tried this but this implementation does not bring the default browser selector up. where am I worng?

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://"));  
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(browserIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    // This is the default browser's packageName
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
```

edit::

```
public void setdef(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    String title = "Select browser";
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
}


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="setdef"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: "this is not showing anything" -- please explain **in detail** what this means.

Comment: see the edit mark